# How to convert an affine matrix to a homography matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-vision

The title is quite self-explanatory, given an affine matrix, is there a way to convert it to a homography matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An affine transformation is a homography.  You can do nothing, and you're done.

Comment: Ouch! That makes every sense... what a dumb question... thank you!

Comment: @hillin There are no dumb questions.  I'm glad I can help.  :)